# Powershell Script to get all groups containing specific name

Tags: powershell, active-directory, directoryservices

Okay, so I am a little new to powershell and I am trying the best I can but cannot seem to get this.

The way my directory is setup is that each organization has their own "Password Reset Group" I will have a scheduled task setup that runs based on the event log entry "Directory Service Change". The script's job is to find members in the groups and reset their password back to their employeeNumber, make the user change the password at next logon and then remove the user from the group. I seem to be having issues getting the syntax correct.

```
Try {
$GroupDN = (Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like '*Password Reset Group*'}).DistinguishedName
}

Catch {
    Write-Host "Unable to locate group: $Group because ""$($Error[0])""" -ForegroundColor Red
    Exit
}
ForEach ($User in (Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties MemberOf,employeeNumber))
{   If ($User.MemberOf -contains $GroupDN)
    {   $password = "$($_.employeeNumber)new!" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
        Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $User -NewPassword $password -Reset
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "$GroupDN" -Members $User

        }
        }
```

Comment: Your `try-catch` block has issues because it will never throw an error. It will only return `$null` if it finds no groups. To access the employeeNumber attribute on each loop, you need to use `$User.employeeNumber`. Also, chances are the `$GroupDN` variable contains an array of distinguishedName property values, so there are going to be issues with your `if` statement.

Comment: It is possible that I misspoke in my previous comment saying that it would "never" throw an error. If you cannot contact a domain controller or ldap server when you run the command or if the ActiveDirectory module has problems loading, it will throw an error. If that is your intention, then you can ignore what I said. However, not being able to find a group from a successful query to AD will not error.

Comment: Okay, so then to fix this how should I modify my script? I am very very new to Powershell and I am trying to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good to see you came up with your own answer, but you can simplify this by just using ...

[Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=win10-ps)

```
# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership ).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership  -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership  -Online
Get-help -Name Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership  -Examples

# Example 2: Get group memberships for the Administrator

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity Administrator
```

... which lists all the groups a user belongs to.

So, your adjustment could be just this...

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | 
ForEach{ 
    # "`n--- Processing user $($PSItem.SamAccountName) ---`n"
    If ($TargetGroup = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $PSItem.SamAccountName) -match 'Password Reset Group')
    {
        $password = "$($PSItem.employeeNumber)new!" | 
        ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

        Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $PSItem.SamAccountName -NewPassword $password -Reset
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup.SamAccountName -Members $PSItem.SameAccountName
    }
}
```

As for …

> Okay, so I am a little new to powershell

… that is all well a good, but it is prudent for you to spend the time getting ramped up on PowerShell to limit / avoid guessing, misconception, frustration, bad habits, errors, etc., that you are going to continue to encounter (even the most experienced of us do and learn from it and each other). There are tons of no cost / free resources all over the we for you to leverage.

Live on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning%20powershell), [MVA](https://mva.microsoft.com/search/SearchResults.aspx#!q=powershell&lang=1033), [MSDN Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Search?term=powershell&lang-en=true) for all the video training. 
Use tools that will write the code for you, that you can save and tweak as needed later. Especially when it comes to ADDS.

[Active Directory Administrative Center: Getting Started](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560651(v=ws.10).aspx)

[Active Directory Administrative Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/adac/active-directory-administrative-center)

[Step-By-Step: Utilizing PowerShell History Viewer in Windows Server 2012 R2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/03/04/step-by-step-utilizing-powershell-history-viewer-in-windows-server-2012-r2)

Free [Books](http://www.powertheshell.com/cookbooks/) and [references](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/183.windows-powershell-survival-guide.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using the information given to me by @AdminOfThings. I was able to write the code I wanted. It took a lot of playing around but here it is:

```
ForEach ($GroupDN in (Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like '*Password Reset Group*'}).DistinguishedName)
    { ForEach ($User in (Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties MemberOf,employeeNumber))
{   If ($User.MemberOf -contains $GroupDN)
    {   $password = $User.employeeNumber | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
        Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $User -NewPassword $password -Reset
        Set-ADUser -Identity $User -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -PasswordNeverExpires $false
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "$GroupDN" -Members $User -Confirm:$false

        }
        }
        }
```